# How to transform current pygame surface to a larger one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Initially I am creating a game surface with dimension WIDTH and HEIGHT

```
pygame.init()
SCREEN1 = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add( ..... #add sprite
...
...

sprites.draw(SCREEN)
SCREEN.blit("test", (WIDTH-4, HEIGHT-2))
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(FPS)
```

How can I transform SCREEN1 to SCREEN2 with a scale of x2? I know there is pygame.transform.scale,
I tried the following but it does not work. It only shows an empty window with new dimension.

```
pygame.init()
SCREEN1 = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add( ..... #add sprite
...
...

sprites.draw(SCREEN)
SCREEN.blit("test", (WIDTH-4, HEIGHT-2))

SCREEN2=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2))
pygame.transform.scale(SCREEN, (WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2), SCREEN2)

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(FPS)
```

May I know what is the proper way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Is the code trying to re-size the window?  Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

`SCREEN` is the display `pygame.Surface` which is associated to the window. When [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) is executed, then a new display surface is generated and the date in the previous display surface is lost. Create a copy of the surface ([`pygame.Surface.copy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy)) before you generate a new display surface:

```py
old_screen = SCREEN.copy()

SCREEN2 = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2))
pygame.transform.scale(old_screen, (WIDTH*2,HEIGHT*2), SCREEN2)
```